# How to get the latest 20 unique things

Tags: time, cassandra

I want to move away from mysql storing visitors in a social media application, and thought cassandra would be fine for that.

Suppose the followign table:

```
CREATE TABLE visitors (
  visiteduserid bigint,
  visitinguserid bigint,
  visitdate timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (visiteduserid,visitinguserid)
);
```

I want to get the latest 20 unique visitinguserid's for the current visiteduserid, but

```
SELECT visitinguserid FROM visitors WHERE visiteduserid=1 ORDER BY visitdate DESC LIMIT 20

Bad Request: Order by is currently only supported on the clustered columns of the PRIMARY KEY, got visitdate
```

Am I right in assuming I can't just add visitdate to the primary key, as I only want to have the latest visitdate for a single user/user combo. Best would be to have them sorted by visitdate descending, as mentioned in the "Twitter Clone" presentation...

Any help out there?

Comment: Patric McFadin presented on timeseries and data modeling at the cassandra summit. Take a look at [his slides](http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/c-summit-2013-the-worlds-next-top-data-model-by-patrick-mcfadin), they are an excellent resource, there is an example with a `user activity` data model that is pretty much what you want. `ALSO` You could add `visitdate` to the compound key and then sort it the way you want.

Comment: It does not seem to be possible in current versions of casssandra.
Implemented a workaround, and now looking into hbase.

Answer (score 2):

You were close. Try this and see how it works for you

```
CREATE TABLE visitors (
  visiteduserid bigint,
  visitdate timestamp,
  visitinguserid bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY (visiteduserid,visitdate)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (visitdate DESC);
```

Then do this:

```
SELECT visitinguserid FROM visitors WHERE visiteduserid=1 LIMIT 20
```

That should do what you are looking for. Relying on the use of a comparator to create the order you want on insert is much more efficient.

Comment: This data model will store each visit though, the OP wants the 20 most recent unique visitors.  If a visitor visits multiple times, there will be duplicates.  However, you can use the query you wrote and page through until you have 20 unique visitors.  This is efficient provided each visitor doesn't visit too often.